# Creating a extra layer in fluent nhibernate models

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In our database we have a `Book` database. This has one of its columns as as `int` called "`NumberOfPages`"

We have a second table called "`BookElements`", This has a number of fields and associates with a Book with `BookId` but each `BookElement` only assoiates with a single Page and so it also has `PageNumber` column.

We can have many BookElements related to a single Page within a Book. I would ideally like to have fluent nhibernate model this in such a way that we have

```
Book.Pages[0].BookElement[0].Name
```

So a single Book has a number of pages (based on its `NumberOfPages` column) which then has a collection of `BookElements` that as associated with that single page.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following:

```
Dictionary<int,IList<BookElement>> BookElements { get; set; }
```

to represent the relation of Page->BookElements

so you can do

```
if( BookElemets.Keys.Contains(pageNum) )
    BookElements[pageNum][elementNum]
```

added solution:

```
class PageElements
{
    public virtual int PageNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<BookElements> { get; set; }
}

class PageElementsMap : ClassMap<PageElements>
{
    public PageElementsMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("ID");

        Map(x => x.PageNumber);

        HasMany(x => x.BookElements)
            .KeyColumn("PageElementsID")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

public virtual IDictionary<int,PageElements> PageElements { get; set; }

class MainEntityMap : ClassMap<MainEntity>
{
    public MainEntityMap()
    {

        ...

        HasMany( x => x.PageElements )
            .AsMap( x=> x.PageNumber )
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();

        ...

    }
}
```

I added a new layer to make it easier to map the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I would not attempt to model the relationship that way. Instead, I would model the relationship as a standard one-to-many and create a method that returns the BookElements for a page:

```
public BookElement[] BookElementsForPage(int pageNumber)
{
    return BookElements.Where(be => be.PageNumber == pageNumber).ToArray();
}
```